# Match any constructor

Tags: types, constructor, pattern-matching, ocaml

Given this type:

```ml
type typeT =
  | A of int
  | B of int
  | C of int
  | D of int
```

I want to simplify the following match (returning a default value when matching D, and the identity otherwise):

```ml
let match_example_1 t =
  match t with
  | A x -> A x 
  | B x -> B x 
  | C x -> C x 
  | D x -> D 1 
  ;;
```

Into something along the lines of this:

```ml
let match_example_2 t = 
  match t with
  | D x -> D 1 
  | f x -> f x
  ;;
```

Or this:

```ml
let match_example_3 t = 
  match t with
  | f x when f == D -> f 1
  | f x -> f x
  ;;
```

But i get a syntax error when matching `f x`. I'm guessing there's something about what constructors actually are in ocaml and the way pattern matching is actually done that i don't understand. I haven't managed to find the reason though, hopefully someone here can help out.

Comment: If this was possible, what would you expect to happen if you add an `E of string`, or `F of int * string` to `typeT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do what you want directly.
You can factorise a bit by matching several things together.

```
match t with
| A x
| B x
| C x -> x 
| D x -> 1
```

This will however not allow you to *get* the `A`, `B` or `C`.

You can however do something closer if you were storing your data differently.

```
type kind = A | B | C | D

type t = kind * int
```

And then do

```
match t with
| (D, x) -> (D, 1)
| (f, x) -> (f, x)
```

Answer (score 2):

@Théo winterhalter
You can use the as construct

```
match t with
| D _ -> D 1
| (A _ | B _ | C _) as x -> x
```

I’m on phone so can test where should be the as (inside or outside the parens).

Answer (score 1):

You could also just return the original value if it doesn't match what you're after:

```
match t with
| D _ -> D 1
| _   -> t
```

What you propose would only be useful if you want to manipulate the contained value, e.g. `f x -> f (x + 1)`, but the questions I asked in the comment above still apply. What if there's a constructor that doesn't follow the exact same shape? What would you expect to happen if you add an `E of string`, or an `F of int * string` to `typeT`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the _ shortcut but you will loose the benefit of exhaustivity checking feature

You can also use something like

```
    match t with
    A x | B x | C x -> f x
    D x -> t
```

This way if in the future the shape of your datastructure change, the type checker will help you in the refactoring process thanks to exhaustivity checking.